# chain Fish commands via `&&` or `||`

Tags: shell, fish

In Bash/ZSH and other shells, I am used to using `&&` and `||`.

Is there any equivalent in Fish?

Comment: This syntax now supported on the master branch and will be released in Fish 3.0 (https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/commit/014b91488db29480160284adfd1cddf286d2888a)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The logical operators you're used to, are supported since fish 3.0.0, released on 2018-12-28.

From the [v3 release notes](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/releases/tag/3.0.0):

> - fish now supports `&&` (like `and`), `||` (like `or`), and `!` (like `not`), for better migration from POSIX-compliant shells ([#4620](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/4620)).

Answer (score 136):

Fish doesn't have a special syntax for a logical AND (`&&`) or a logical OR (`||`).

Instead, you can use the commands `and` and `or`, which verify the previous command's exit status and act accordingly:

```
command1
and command2
```

```
command1
or command2
```

Furthermore – just like in bash – you can use a semicolon `;` to execute two commands one after the other:

```
command1 ; command2
```

This allows using a more familiar syntax:

```
command1 ;and command2
command1 ;or command2
```

See http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_combiners

Comment: There's an open github issue to add support for this syntax: [&& doesn't work · Issue #150 · fish-shell/fish-shell](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/150)

Comment: `This allows using a more familiar syntax:` is very subjective

Comment: `;and` is less readable than `&&` as the semicolon suggests a logically disjoint operation. It's visually jarring.

Comment: @Elliott I agree, but Fish doesn't give you a choice.

Comment: do note though that in fish and bourne shells, AND and OR operators have the same order, unlike C based languages: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88851/50703

Comment: @dennis which is a good thing: there's only one option, and you don't **have to choose**, it's already chosen for you. Plus I think that using a "native" solution instead of implementing a new syntax if far better, even though it might now look as good (and, as petr said, it's very subjective).

Comment: You can't do `command1 and command2` though, command 2 will never be run because "and" will be considered as argument 1 for command1, and command2 will be considered as argument 2 for command1. For example `if true and true; echo yes; end` won't work because fish will think you're passing the arguments "and true" to the command true. `if true; and true; echo yes; end` is the correct way.