# How do I run make && make install while in fish shell

Tags: bash, fish

I have installed the fish shell, and I'm very happy with it ... but I cannot run the following command:

```
make && make install
```

This works nicely in bash... How do I run it in fish shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [chain Fish commands via \`&&\` or \`||\`](http://superuser.com/questions/446930/chain-fish-commands-via-or)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/user_doc/html/commands.html):

> The and builtin is used to execute a command if the current exit status (as set by the last previous command) is 0.
>
> ```
> COMMAND1; and COMMAND2
> ```

So you'd call:

```
make; and make install
```