# How to chain a group of commands in Fish like { … } Bash?

Tags: shell, shell-script, fish

I'm aware of [chain Fish commands via `&&` or `||`](https://superuser.com/q/446930/174465) but I'm willing to chain a set of command**s**

#### Code

```
env git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/rafaelrinaldi/theme-pure.git; or {
    printf "Error: git clone of theme-pure repo failed\n"
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: Use `begin; commands; end` instead of `{ commands; }` -- http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#begin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `begin` and `end` keywords to solve this (thanks to [glenn jackman](https://superuser.com/users/4714/glenn-jackman) comment):

```
env git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/rafaelrinaldi/theme-pure.git; or begin;
    printf "Error: git clone of theme-pure repo failed\n"
    exit 1
end
```

#### Doc

See official doc [begin - start a new block of code](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#begin).